# Regex with an optional group part

Tags: regex

I have these two kinds of string to match and group:

```
<133>[S=88121248] [SID:1073710562] (   lgr_psbrdif)(72811810  )   #38:OpenChannel:on Trunk 0 BChannel:9 CID=38 with VoiceCoder: g711Alaw64k20 VbdCoder: InvalidCoder255 DetectorSide: 0 FaxModemDet NO_FAX_MODEM_DETECTED
```

and

```
<133>[S=88209541] (     sip_stack)(73281971  )   TcpTransportObject#430::DispatchQueueEvent(EVENT_RECEIVER_DISCONNECT) - Closing connection
```

I need to match both and get specific group. I use this pattern:

```
<(.*)>\[S=(.*)\] (\[SID:(.*?)\])?(.*)
```

What I match is:

```
Match0: <133>[S=88121248] [SID:1073710562] ......the full line  
Group1: 133  
Group2: 88121248] [SID:1073710562  
Group3:  
Group4:  
Group5: ......the full line  

Match1: <133>[S=88209541] ......the full line  
Group1: 133  
Group2: 88209541  
Group3:   
Group4:  
Group5: ......the full line
```

What I need:

```
Match0: <133>[S=88121248] [SID:1073710562] ......the full line  
Group1: 133  
Group2: 88121248  
Group3: 1073710562  
Group4:  
Group5: ......the full line  


Match1: <133>[S=88209541] ......the full line  
Group1: 133  
Group2: 88209541  
Group3:  
Group4:  
Group5: ......the full line
```

To resume the match on both are fine, but grouping is not. The second string is matched and grouped fine, but the first not.

Comment: `<(.*)>\[S=(.*?)\] (?:\[SID:(.*?)\])?(.*)` use this.

Comment: Don't forget to either close the thread (by accepting the response, if it solved your problem) or keep the thread alive (by commenting, if there is still an issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a typical mistake by using the greedy star `.*` and thereby overshooting your intended match.

To match anything between two delimiters, it's better to use negated character class instead, for example `<([^>]*)>` between `<` and `>`.

So this would work:

```
^<([^>]*)>\[S=([^\]]*)\]\s+(?:\[SID:([^\]]*)\]\s+)?(.*)
```

Breakdown:

```
^<([^>]*)>                # something between < and > at the start of the line
\[S=([^\]]*)\]\s+         # something between "[S=" and "]"
(?:\[SID:([^\]]*)\]\s+)?  # something between "[SID:" and "]", optional
(.*)                      # rest of the string
```

Note the non-capturing parentheses `(?:...)` that get rid of the unused group in the result.

Matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-4]   `133`
2.  [8-16]  `88121248`
3.  [23-33] `1073710562`
4.  [35-218]    `(   lgr_psbrdif)(72811810  )   #38:OpenChannel:on Trunk 0 BChannel:9 CID=38 with VoiceCoder: g711Alaw64k20 VbdCoder: InvalidCoder255 DetectorSide: 0 FaxModemDet NO_FAX_MODEM_DETECTED `

MATCH 2
1.  [220-223]   `133`
2.  [227-235]   `88209541`
3.  n/a
4.  [237-360]   `(     sip_stack)(73281971  )   TcpTransportObject#430::DispatchQueueEvent(EVENT_RECEIVER_DISCONNECT) - Closing connection  `
```